# Looping through objects in Angular HTTP request, wait until response before running next loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have this code:

```
// HTTP request
$http.get(dataSource).
then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // Products array
    var products = [];

    // Loop through each array value
    for (var slug in data.data){

        var product = data.data[slug];
        $http.get('content/products/' + product + '.json').then(function(response){

            products.push(response.data);
            $scope.products = products;

        }).catch(function(){

            console.log('there was an error');

        });

    }

}).catch(function(){
    console.log('there was an error');
});
```

The issue is that sometimes the product scope array items do not arrive always in the same order they are requested.

I need the products $scope to loop through the array and only when the response has been pushed to the array:

```
products.push(response.data);
```

that is finally assigned to the variable `$scope.products`.

Any help with modifying my current HTTP request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem resides in the for loop, that is synchronous, containing asynchronous code. In practice there is no guarantee that the inner http.get processes data in the same order it is get.

Try this:

```
// HTTP request
$http.get(dataSource).
  then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // Products array
    var products = [];

    // Loop through each array value
    var promises = [];
    for (var slug in data.data){

      var product = data.data[slug];
      promises.push($http.get('content/products/' + product + '.json'));
    }

    $q.all(promises).then(function(response){

      for (var i=0,len = response.length;i<len;++i){

        products.push(response[i].data);

      }
      $scope.products = products;

    }).catch(function(){

        console.log('there was an error');

    });

  }).catch(function(){

    console.log('there was an error');

  });
```

I suggest to use `$q.all()` to preserve the order of the http.get results. Look also that `$scope.products` is after the for loop that assigns data values to `products` array as you specified.

Comment: Thanks! Looking good up until the product.push. 'resp.data' is undefined. If I console log the response I get the correct objects of data, the for loop isn't working as expected. Console logging 'resp' in the loop simply returns the object index number, (0,1,2,3,5). Any ideas?

Comment: actually, sorted it now. In the for loop had to do products.push(response[resp].data)

Comment: @Lovelock ok anyway I replaced the for( ..in..) loop with the traditional one.